# drupal 7.67 AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally batch processing

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, https, drupal, batch-processing

The complete error is:
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=55 &op=do StatusText: ResponseText: ReadyState: 0

when I send the newsletter and after 30 min the batch progress bar stops and shows me the error above.
this error product on an https domain (the sending of the newsletter stops but when I refresh the page the sending continues) .
I tested with another domain http (without https) on the same server is it works well

https it's valid until 2020,about this error Ajax I did not find more information in the logs apart in the chrome console using the extension ajax debugger "error connection reset" and in server "internal dummy connexion "

now the question I ask myself is about the server configuration ? the batch has to work with an http domain and it does not work with an https domain, what's the problem? is it necessary to increase some parameters in php.ini starting for example max_input_vars (1000) or max_input_nesting_leve (64) or post_max_size (8M) or mysql max_allowed_packet (256M)? or add the line $ conf ['https'] = TRUE; in drupal setting?